# how to create text image on the fly and embed it with email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, bitmap, jpeg

I think we can create a text image and convert it to jpeg file by doing some code like this  but how to embed this image  with mail and send.any help is appreciated

```
string Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Text"]; 
Color FontColor = Color.Blue; 
Color BackColor = Color.White; 
String FontName = "Times New Roman"; 
int FontSize = 10; 
int Height = 150; 
int Width = 150;

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height); 
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap); 
Color color = Color.Gray; 
System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontName, FontSize);
PointF point = new PointF(5.0F, 5.0F); 

SolidBrush BrushForeColor = new SolidBrush(FontColor);
SolidBrush BrushBackColor = new SolidBrush(BackColor);
Pen BorderPen = new Pen(color); 

System.Drawing.Rectangle displayRectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(Width - 1, Height - 1));
graphics.FillRectangle(BrushBackColor, displayRectangle);
graphics.DrawRectangle(BorderPen, displayRectangle);
StringFormat format1 = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
StringFormat format2 = new StringFormat(format1);
graphics.DrawString(Text, font, Brushes.Red, (RectangleF)displayRectangle, format2);

HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
bitmap.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Since you will also need `ContentLength`, save it to MemoryStream and then copy it to Response.OutputStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code sample below skips creating the message and adding the subject, body and addresses. It shows the code used to embed an image that is initially stored in a byte array. The key is to get your image into a memory stream.

```
//... other System.Net.Mail.MailMessage creation code
// CustomerSignature is a byte array containing the image
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(CustomerSignature);
System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType();
contentType.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
contentType.Name = "signature.jpg";
System.Net.Mail.Attachment imageAttachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, contentType);
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(imageAttachment);
System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource signature = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(ms, "image/jpeg");
signature.ContentId = "CustomerSignature";
System.Net.Mail.AlternateView aView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailMessage.Body, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html"));
aView.LinkedResources.Add(signature);
mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(aView);
```

I had issues where the embedded image was shown in some email programs, and not others. I modified the line that creates the linked resource, and the line that creates the new AlternativeView and the image is now viewable across a wider range of programs.